# Git undo changes to some files while keeping others that involves large number of files

Tags: git, version-control

I am using git-bash on Windows. I made a change that affects multiple files (around 500)

Now, the problem is half of the changes should not happen and I need to undo all the changes made to those files. All changes are unstaged changes.

If it involved only few files (10-15) I could simply add the files I need one by one and stash the rest using `git stash -u --keep-index`. But the number of files involved makes it more difficult to use `git add` or `git checkout -- filename` and process each file.

Any suggestion how to handle such a large number of files and either add the ones I need at once or revert the changes for the unwanted files?

Thank you

Comment: How did you make *a change that affects multiple files (around 500)*? In an automated fashion, using some kind of script? If so, it might easier to just discard all unstaged changes, fix your script so that it only affects the files of interest, and run the script again.

Comment: Well, if you cannot specify programmatically which of the files should be reset, you'll have to specify them one by one; Git cannot read your mind.

Comment: How can something automatically know which changes need to be kept and which ones discarded? Do you need to throw away all changes to files with a particular extension? All files in a particular directory? Git (well, more likely bash, but it amounts to the same thing) can help with some things like this, but there's got to be a way of distinguishing the files.

Comment: @Jubobs I understand your point, maybe I need to write a script to make these changes. I wanted to see if there are some features in git that will allow you achieve this. FYI these files(Java classes) are auto-generated in a way similar to Entity classes are generated using Hibernate tools.

Comment: @Chris yes the files names have a specific pattern, the ones I need to revert and those that I don't. So, I am asking if Git has a way of running a command similar to `git checkout -- pathToFiles\*somePattern.java`

Comment: @user624558, in non-Windows environments it's usual for the *shell* (e.g. `bash`) do do wildcard expansion, not the application (e.g. `git`). Since the shell that ships with Git is a Unix-style shell, it works this way too. Can you share the pattern that you'd like to use?

Comment: @Chris thank you for your help. Both file types are found in the same package, so sharing the same dir(`projectName/src/com/mycomp/files/file.java`). Those I need to reset have a pattern similar to `NameOfTheTableEntity.java`(`NameOfTheTable` contains no numbers and special chars with camel-case writing). The other group has a similar pattern, the only difference is the term `Main` is added at the end, so the naming becomes `NameOfTheTableEntityMain.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do what you're trying to do is to leverage the [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) utility. Note that this is different from Windows' `find`; if you're using Git bash you should have the correct one available.

Since `find` can be a bit tricky, I like to make sure that it is giving the results that I expect by `echo`ing out what it will do:

```
find src/com/mycomp/files -type f -name "*.java" ! -name "*Main.java" -exec echo git checkout -- {} \;
```

I'll break down the command here:

- `find` is the command you're running
- `src/com/mycomp/files` is the root directory in which to look
- `-type f` says to only consider files, not directories or symlinks
- `-name "*.java"` says to look at files ending in `.java`, but
- `! -name "*Main.java"` says not to include anything ending in `Main.java`
- `-exec` tells `find` to run the following command on the files it finds
- `echo` prints out its arguments, effectively letting us preview our command
- `git checkout -- {}` is the commmand that we eventually want to run, with the file names found by `find` replacing `{}`
- and finally, `\;` says to run the command once for each file, instead of treating all of them together.

If everything looks correct, I edit the command to remove `echo` and run it again.